# How much time does it take to start new instance of existing role

Tags: azure

For example, I have web role and 2 instances for it. I want to add one more instance of my web role (via service API and C#). How much time dose this operation take in average? What are the MIN and MAX of this value?

Answer (score 1):

Varies widely based on size and complexity of the role. Best way to benchmark this that I can think of is to deploy multiple times and measure your times and take an average. Just be careful as sub-hour deployments count as full hours so you can easily start running up your compute bill. Hence why I normally don't worry about it too much and just use a ballpark of 10-15 minutes. :)